# using react-native-router-flux together with DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm curious as to whether I've build my app's structure correctly or entirely wrong.
This is what I have so far in my `routes.js`:

```
 render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady)
            return <Splash/>
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}} backButtonTintColor={color.black}>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login"/>
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="DrawNav" drawer hideNavBar component={DrawNav} title={"Home"} type = {ActionConst.REPLACE}/>
                        <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"}/>                                                        
                        <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back/> 
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )
    }
```

Now this might seem odd but I have decided to use `DrawerNavigator` to define my `DrawNav` component like so:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1
  },
  itemContainer:{
    marginTop:20
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:color.blue,
    borderRadius: 4
  }
});

//Edit drawer layout here
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
  <View style = {styles.container}>
    <View style = {styles.itemContainer}>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </View>
    <Button title="Logout" onPress={props.screenProps} buttonStyle={styles.button}/>
  </View>
);

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    About: {
      screen: aboutScreen
    },
    Setting:{
      screen: settingScreen
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  }
);

class DrawNav extends React.Component{  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onSignOut = this.onSignOut.bind(this);
  }

  onSuccess() {
    this.props.actionsHome.successSignOut();
    Actions.reset("Auth");
  }

  onError(error) {
    Alert.alert('Oops!', error.message);
  }

  onSignOut() {
    this.props.actionsAuth.signOut(this.onSuccess.bind(this),this.onError.bind(this))
  }

  render(){
      return <Drawer screenProps = {this.onSignOut}/>;  
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (DrawNav);
```

But now I'm starting to doubt what I've done here, problem is, if say I wanna do do several `<Stacks>` containing several `<Scenes>` like so in my `routes.js`:

```
<Stack key="main">
   <Scene key="DrawNav">
       <Stack key="HomeStack">
           <Scene key="Home">
           <Scene key="ItemDescription">
       <Stack key="OrderStack">
           <Scene key="Orders">
           <Scene key="AddOrders">
```

I would have to be able to put the `HomeStack` and `OrderStack` in the `DrawNav` somehow.

Am I doing something I shouldn't here?

How do I better structure the collaboration between `RNRF` and `DrawerNavigator` to achieve what I described above?

Comment: you shouldn't be using `react-navigation` together with `react-native-router-flux`.

Comment: @riwu thanks for the quick response! this is what I needed to confirm. Should I just create my own drawer component then? or is there a better lib?

Comment: `react-native-router-flux` does support [Drawer](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#drawer-drawer-or-scene-drawer)? If you need further customisation and the API doesn't support it, then you should switch to `react-navigation`. `react-native-router-flux` is just a wrapper around `react-navigation` so it might have missing features.

Comment: @riwu hmm yes actually the fact that `RNRF` is a wrapper for `react-navigation` is the reason why I thought it would be alright to use `DrawerNavigator` together with it in the first place. It's because I felt like the `Drawer` from `RNRF` is abit limiting, but I already built my the whole thing on `RNRF` and DrawerNav is just the latest addition, so I think I will say pass to moving to `react-navigation` altogether and just try to make do with `RNRF`. Thanks so much for the help!